# Is there any way to get default parameter value for verilog module with Yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am trying to get default parameter values for verilog modules using Yosys command shell.
Is there any way to do it?
In addition, is parsing a `write_ilang' command output file a good idea or its format can change dramatically in the near future?

Attempts were made to find default values in ilang, json, table dumps and even using `chparam -list` command, but they did not bring any result.

Consider this example (file param_test.v):

```
module stub();
  parameter PUBLIC_PARAM = 1;
  parameter HIDDEN_PARAM = 2;
endmodule

module testbench();
  stub no_param_stub ();
  stub #(.PUBLIC_PARAM(1)) one_param_stub ();
endmodule
```

I follow these steps:

1. load source code `read -sv param_test.v`
2. elaborate design `hierarchy -top testbench`
3. try to get parameter values.

Output from `write_ilang` command:

```
# Generated by Yosys 0.8+634 (git sha1 ac2fc3a, clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 -fPIC -Os)
autoidx 1
attribute \blackbox 1
attribute \src "param_test.v:1"
module $paramod\stub\PUBLIC_PARAM=1
  parameter \HIDDEN_PARAM
  parameter \PUBLIC_PARAM
end
attribute \blackbox 1
attribute \src "param_test.v:1"
module \stub
  parameter \HIDDEN_PARAM
  parameter \PUBLIC_PARAM
end
attribute \top 1
attribute \src "param_test.v:6"
module \testbench
  attribute \module_not_derived 1
  attribute \src "param_test.v:8"
  cell \stub \no_param_stub
  end
  attribute \module_not_derived 1
  attribute \src "param_test.v:10"
  cell $paramod\stub\PUBLIC_PARAM=1 \one_param_stub
  end
end
```

Output from `write_json` command does not even contain information about the `HIDDEN_PARAM` parameter:

```
{
  "creator": "Yosys 0.8+634 (git sha1 ac2fc3a, clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 -fPIC -Os)",
  "modules": {
    "$paramod\\stub\\PUBLIC_PARAM=1": {
      "attributes": {
        "blackbox": 1,
        "src": "param_test.v:1"
      },
      "ports": {
      },
      "cells": {
      },
      "netnames": {
      }
    },
    "stub": {
      "attributes": {
        "blackbox": 1,
        "src": "param_test.v:1"
      },
      "ports": {
      },
      "cells": {
      },
      "netnames": {
      }
    },
    "testbench": {
      "attributes": {
        "top": 1,
        "src": "param_test.v:6"
      },
      "ports": {
      },
      "cells": {
        "no_param_stub": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "type": "stub",
          "parameters": {
          },
          "attributes": {
            "module_not_derived": 1,
            "src": "param_test.v:8"
          },
          "port_directions": {
          },
          "connections": {
          }
        },
        "one_param_stub": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "type": "$paramod\\stub\\PUBLIC_PARAM=1",
          "parameters": {
          },
          "attributes": {
            "module_not_derived": 1,
            "src": "param_test.v:10"
          },
          "port_directions": {
          },
          "connections": {
          }
        }
      },
      "netnames": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yosys recently gained the functionality to preserve parameters through elaboration (whereas they are usually thrown away). Add `-pwires` to `read_verilog` and parameters will be converted into wires driven by the parameter's default value with the `parameter` attribute set to 1.

In terms of stability, there are several other tools (such as nMigen) that create or read RTLIL ilang, so it is unlikely to have significant breaking changes now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is unfortunate that `-pwires` flag is not described in the documentation.
I also found another way to get to the initial values of the parameters through C++ API.
It is possible to `dynamic_cast` Yosys::RTLIL::Module to Yosys::AST::AstModule after elaboration and access it parameter values. However, i guess it is a bad long-term solution.

Comment: FYI, `-pwires` is documented if you run `help read_verilog` (and will appear in the online documentation once 0.9 is released.9).